# How to implement a predictive model (10 types with 100 parameters) in C++ when a DLL (+header) is the expected delivery?

Tags: python, c++, dll, machine-learning, runtime

My desktop application process documents (10 types exist) to provide intelligence using 100s of parameters. Thru supervised training, I came up with a predictive model that uses 100 of the parameters to indicate whether a document is a reliable source of information or not. The training and testing of the Machine Learning model was done in Python. Currently I need to implement the prediction part, which uses the parameters weights from the training part, into my [MFC/VC++] desktop application.

The suggested architecture is to provide a DLL plus header that exposes a function:

`bool isDocumentReliable(int docID)`

Based on the type of the document, the prediction uses a set of parameters to calculate the probability of the document being reliable. Based on risk assessment (requirements of the business) we translate the probability into a `true/false` answer.

I am looking for some architectural/implementation information to guide my implementation.

That's my first Machine Learning project and my questions are:

1. What are the questions I need to be asking?
2. Should the parameters be hard-coded into my functions? or
3. Should the parameters be read from text files at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the function should be `bool isDocumentReliable(std::wstring pathname)`, but that's a minor detail. The main question, *by far*, should be: How are we going to prototype this? Don't expect this to work straight away.

If you've got a boss that thinks Machine Learning is like writing software, and it either works or not, tell him he's flat out wrong.